# Custom intellisense auto completion in vscode: how to dynamically point intellisense to a class or another?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

my question is simple but I can't find any relevant documentation or code example that points me to the right direction.

I have a modular javascript architecture where modules are **registered** at startup in a `moduleService`.
So when I call `moduleService.moduleA.myMethod()`, it does not provide any suggestion because `moduleService` is just instanciated as an empty service and constructed dynamically.

I'm planning to make a vscode extension that could be able to find all registered modules, and for each, get the corresponding classes and provide completion and method documentation.

Have you got a clue on how to achieve that ?

Comment: VSCode only wants you to provide a completion item provider, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider The actual implementation is up to you.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I have tested this method. That is good expect I don't find how I can register completions dynamically (searching method names relevant to the class name I'm wrinting). It seems to works only for static words (more like snippets).

Comment: @TOPKAT Did you ever find a solution you're happy with?

Comment: @chris Now I use a custom prebuid phase where I generate files AND file.d.ts (types) alongside. So every time I start the server, new type files are generated and updated. I didn't find a better way for now although I have being deep in searching...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a code completion provider for that functionality. Instead provide a typings file with the definitions from your modules and make this available to vscode. It will then happily show the info in its normal completion suggestions.

How you make your typings file available in the source tree is up to you. I simply placed mine in node_modules/@types/mymodule/mymodule.d.ts and that was it.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I'm not in typescript and I want to avoid maintaining a separate typing file if possible. Thanks however :)

Comment: Ha! The good news is you don't need to work in typescript :-) Visual Studio Code also uses typings files for JS files. This is what we do with a duktape project that implements the code actually in C++, so there cannot be any JS/TS code for code completion. Instead I wrote a typings file that contains all the details and made it available in the scripting code.